# How to properly do a "bind" in angular2 typescript?

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to use a javascript library that requires creating an object and binding to it like this:

```
this.mystr = "hello";
this.webkitspeech = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
this.webkitspeech.onresult = function(evt) {
    console.log(this.mystr); // this is undefined, even though I do have it defined
}
```

I would usually do a `.bind(this)`

Though in typescript I want to do this:

```
this.mystr = "hello"
this.webkitspeech = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
this.webkitspeech.onresult = onresult;

onresult(event) {    
    console.log(this.mystr) // this is undefined, even though I do have it defined
}
```

The `.bind(this)` does not work in this example. How do I get around this? Are there alternatives to just doing `.bind(this)`? Or whatever works for typescript functions?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In TypeScript as well as in ES6 the most convenient way to bind a function is to use [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) which preserves the context:

```
this.webkitspeech.onresult = ($event) => { this.onresult($event) };
```

Or use `bind` like this:

```
this.webkitspeech.onresult = this.onresult.bind(this);
```

Or you can use TS instance arrow function (ES class property) like this:

```
class MyClass() {
   onresult = ($event) => {...}
   ...
   this.webkitspeech.onresult = onresult;
}
```

Class properties is [stage 2 ES7 proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-public-fields) which is supported in TS today.

[See the documentation](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/%27this%27-in-TypeScript#fixes) for some comparison between the methods.

Comment: See also https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/%27this%27-in-TypeScript#fixes

Comment: @yurzui, thanks, these are the 3 methods I've mentioned as well. I've put the reference into the answer

Comment: What about how to get a reference to this.mystr? WiIl that be defined or undefined?

Comment: @Rolando, `this` will pointing to the class instance so you will have access to all `class` members including `mystr`