# Angular 2 Constructor ngOnInit undefined property TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase

I am trying to initialize an object's value from data returned from a (Firebase) data store. I can see the data being returned, but i cannot assign it to a local variable. I am teaching myself TypeScript, Angular 2 and Firebase, so this might be a 'duh' question...

```
import ProfileProvider from ../providers/profile

@Component({...})
class Profile {
userProfile:any

constructor (public profileProvider: ProfilePRovider) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.profileProvider.getUSerProfile().on ("value", function(snap) { 
    console.log(snap.val()); // this works, prints all my data correctly
    this.userProfile = snap.val(); // this fails, "cannot set property userProfile of undefined"
   }
 }
}
```

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: this also [How to properly do a “bind” in angular2 typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45136760/2545680)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `this` does not refer the component itself. Either bind the function or use `fat arrow =>` function:

```
...getUserProfile().on('value', function(snap){
  }.bind(this))
```

or

```
...getUserProfile().on('value', snap => {
  // this is properly bound here
  });
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm new to JavaScript / Type Script, this was driving me crazy... Not a fan of either language...

Comment: Well, be patient, you'll get it and enjoy it.

Comment: I may eventually get it, I'm not sure I'll enjoy it... :)