# Angular 2: parent class dependency injected is undefined

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, routes, angular2-services

I'm trying a implement a service which all other services would extend to handle api responses. I followed this question

[Inheritance and dependency injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39038791/inheritance-and-dependency-injection)

and here is my parent class:

```
import {Injector} from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from "@angular/router";
import {Response} from "@angular/http";

export class ApiService {

  protected _router: Router;

  constructor(injector: Injector) {
    console.log('inside ApiService constructor');
    this._router = injector.get(Router);
    console.log(this._router);
  }

  extractData(res: Response) {
    if (res.json().status === 200) {
      return res.json().data;
    }
  }

  extractResponse(res: Response) {
    if (res.json().status === 200) {
      return res.json();
    }
  }

  handleErrorPromise(error: Response | any) {
    console.log('inside handleErrorPromise');
    console.error(error.message || error);
    console.log(this._router);

    if (error.status === 401 || error.status === "401") {
      // session out
      this._router.navigate(['/login']);
    } else {
      return Promise.reject(error.json().message | error.message || error);
    }
  }

}
```

and here's the service that extends it:

```
@Injectable()
export class VitalService extends ApiService {

  constructor(private http: Http, injector: Injector) {
    super(injector);
  }

  getUserVitals(): Promise<VitalDashboardItem[]> {
    return this.http.get('/gch-restful/vital-entry/dashboard')
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => {
        return response.json().data as VitalDashboardItem[];
      })
      .catch(this.handleErrorPromise);
  }

}
```

but when it reaches the handleErrorPromise in super class

I'm getting this error:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property '_router' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property '_router' of undefined
```

I been trying to figure what's wrong for a while now, tried a few things and had no luck. Any help is appreciated

**EDIT**

changed it like this:

```
getUserVitals(): Promise<VitalDashboardItem[]> {
    return this.http.get('/gch-restful/vital-entry/dashboard')
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => {
        return response.json().data as VitalDashboardItem[];
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        return this.handleErrorPromise(e)
      });
  }
```

Comment: `console.log(this._router);` what are you getting here?

Comment: it is not undefined there. prints the router object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're losing the `this` context here:

```
.catch(this.handleErrorPromise);
```

change it to:

```
.catch((e) => { this.handleErrorPromise(e) });
```

See  [How to properly do a “bind” in angular2 typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45136760/2545680) for information.

Comment: sorry, but it still shows Cannot read property '_router' of undefined

Comment: console.log(this._router); inside handleErrorPromise method

Comment: how did you modify the code? show the updated version

Comment: i put console.log(this); just before console.log(this._router); and it prints undefined

Comment: did you udpate the `.catch((e) => { this.handleErrorPromise(e) });`? if so, put a log here `.catch((e) => { console.log(this._router); this.handleErrorPromise(e) });`

Comment: it is not undefined there, prints the router object

Comment: and you also see `inside handleErrorPromise` but the next statement `console.log(this._router);` logs undefined?

Comment: console.log(this._router); inside handleErrorPromise throws error Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property '_router' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property '_router' of undefined. I added console.log(this) before before console.log(this._router); in handleErrorPromise. It prints undefined

Comment: well, create a plunker then. If you have `this._router` here `.catch((e) => { console.log(this._router); this.handleErrorPromise(e) });` it should be available inside `this.handleErrorPromise(e)` because `this` references the same object and you're not overwriting it inside the method

Comment: I found that it is when I refresh the page by clicking browser refresh button that console.log(this) prints undefined. Do you any idea why?