# angular 5: pass a callback method to 3rd party script with angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I **really** an imported 3rd party script to trigger a function like `show_end_screen` (below)

my component

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { init_game, start_game, stop_game } from '../../assets/js/game';

@Component({})

export class PlayComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(public router:Router) {}
    ngOnInit() {
        init_game(this.show_end_screen) // load ready
    }
    show_end_screen(data){
        console.log(data) //this works
        this.router.navigate(['play']); //"this" is undefined
    }
}
```

`init_game(this.show_end_screen)` <== Here I am passing `show_end_screen` to the imported script. when the 3rd party script runs `show_end_screen(data)` I successfully log `data` to the console. But i dont have access to `this` or any other reference to angular

`this.router.navigate(['play']);` <== here i get a console error

`ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'nav' of undefined`

Comment: Where do you define `router` in your component?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: This question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45136760/822947)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly do a "bind" in angular2 typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45136680/how-to-properly-do-a-bind-in-angular2-typescript)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you pass a class-bound method as a value it loses the context (`this`). You can bind explicitly or call within the callback:

```
ngOnInit() {
  // explicit binding
  init_game(this.show_end_screen.bind(this));

  // lexical binding
  init_game(data => this.show_end_screen(data));
}
```

You can also use an instance-bound method for your component instead.

```
show_end_screen = (data) => {
  this.router.navigate(['play']);
}
```

Comment: so glad to have your help! `.bind(this)` ... will that change how the callback is used in the other script?

Comment: I dont understand how it works but It did... Need to study up... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is because `this` refers to the calling context, not the context from which you assign your callback. You should be able to make this work, by explicitly defining which context `this` refers to by using the `bind` function.

So your code would look like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    init_game(this.show_end_screen.bind(this))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming `this.router` is defined in your constructor

In addition to @Explossion Pills answer, you could  define your method as a property and save that `bind()` call

```
show_end_screen = (data) => {
  console.log(data) //this works
  this.router.navigate(['play']); //"this" is undefined
}
```